# Convert a tab-delimited file to use newlines

Tags: text-processing

input.txt (around 30K lines)

```
RT|367079254|bn|ERTS01065811.1| 38 1 503
RT|367079251|bn|ERTS01065814.1| 56 3 502
RT|367079248|bn|ERTS01065817.1| 52 2 502
```

output.txt

```
RT|367079254|bn|ERTS01065811.1|
38
1
503
RT|367079251|bn|ERTS01065814.1|
56
3
502
RT|367079248|bn|ERTS01065817.1|
52
2
502
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Sed`:

```
sed -e 'y/\t/\n/' input.txt > output.txt
```

`Awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\n" } { $1=$1; print }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 27):

I think your easiest way to do this is with `tr`:

```
tr '\t' '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

That'll turn all the tabs to newlines.

[tr - Man Page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html)

Comment: Easiest and fastest, too.

Comment: You should have been awarded this answer, as `tr` was the best solution. Both `sed`, and `awk`, while great tools, are overkill.

Answer (score 0):

With `printf` :

```
printf '%s\n' $(<FILE)
```

Comment: I wonder why this was down-voted.

Comment: Possibly because this will split on spaces not just tabs.